# Сообщения нотификаций переведены частично, когда находишься на англоязычном сайте

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация, уведомления

Не знаю даже, считать это багой или нет, но выглядит неаккуратно. Когда я на русскоязычном сайте, я вижу нормально переведённое уведомление о новом значке:

[image: Russian]

А когда я на англоязычном, это выглядит некрасиво:

[image: English]

Мне кажется, стоит либо полностью локализовать уведомления с другого сайта (писать как на русском), либо уж вообще не переводить ни название значка, ни описание (писать «You've earned the "Excavator" badge (blah blah) for "..."», заголовок вопроса придётся, конечно, оставить на русском).

Comment: Ну это как бы не баг, ведь на каждом сайте свои значки. Вы получили значок на ru.so, а не на en.so, поэтому логично будет отображать название и описание значка с того сайта, на котором значок получен

Comment: @BOPOH: оба раза информация про значок на ru.so — посмотрите на логотип.

Comment: Это определенно не баг перевода, это особенность движка. На каком бы сайте вы ни находились, вы видите весь интерфейс на языке этого сайта. Можно проверить на португальском SO: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/. Если менять функциональность, то тут, пожалуй, нужен feature-request на Meta.SE.

Comment: Кстати, регулярно читаю ваши статьи на Хабре )

Comment: так я про то и говорю - вы на so увидели значок с ru.so, логично отображать название значка с ru.so (вы ведь его там получили), а не аналог на so. К тому же - на сайте могут быть свои значки. И как-то глупо будет в таком случае требовать, чтобы pt.so переводил какие-то непонятные для него значки с ru.so

Comment: Ну мне бы казалось логичнее, если бы вся строка выводилась на русском (первый из предложенных мной вариантов). Эти «for» и «badge» посреди в целом русской фразы смотрятся странно :-) Да, я понял, что это не вопрос русской локализации, а движка в целом. @NickVolynkin, как их можно регулярно читать, если я уж несколько месяцев не писал ничего? =)

Comment: @TagirValeev: много читал этой весной. Про локализацию: конечно, логичнее, если из базы будет запрашиваться не только локализованное название знака, но и строка для его описания.

Comment: Аналогично происходит, если заработать значок на en.SO: нотификация на ru.SO приходит на русском, а названия — на английском.

Comment: Сейчас тяжело сказать, что именно не так. Как я писал в другом вопросе, вследствие переезда серверов, часть строк стали недоступны. Надеюсь, в ближайшее время ошибка будет устранена, и можно будет точно сказать, что именно не так.